# Trim data from CSV file after a Special Character in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, trim

I am trying to read data from csv file i am using Import-csv cmdlet. this csv file has SQL Server data with instance names as below

```
Instance

Test

Test1\002

Test2

Test3\001
```

I want to trim the instance name and read only server name from the csv file. Looking for help for achieving this.

I am preparing a report with the details of the SQL Server services:

my script is as follows

```
$InputFile = Import-Csv "C:\Test\SQLInstance.csv"

foreach($Servers in $Inputfile)
{
Write-Host "ServerName:" $Servers.instance
Get-WmiObject win32_service  -ComputerName $Servers.instance  | Select Name, Startmode, State  | Where-Object `
{$_.name -like "*SQL*" -and $_.Startmode -match "Auto" -and $_.state -match "Stopped"} | FT -AutoSize
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test to remove the trailling characters using `-replace` operator and a regular expression  test:

```
"test\001" -replace '\\.*$',''
"test1" -replace '\\.*$',''
```

So you can write :

```
$serverName = $Servers.instance -replace '\\.*$',''
```

Comment: Perfect. $InputFile = Import-Csv "C:\Test\SQLInstance.csv" | %{ $_.Instance = $_.Instance -replace "\\.*$" ; $_}